# Why result of getLocationInWindow for View doesn't appropriate in TranslateAnimation?

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, view

To train myself, I created some clone of 2048-game. The program works quite good, but today I wanted to add to it the animation for moving cells. This is my layout (do not swear, if my code looks like a dump, I tried to make it as good as possible, but I still have much to learn):

```
    <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.FieldView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="60dp"
        android:focusable="true">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25">
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell0"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell1"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell2"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell3"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25">
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell4"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell5"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell6"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell7"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25">
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell8"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell9"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell10"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell11"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25">
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell12"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell13"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell14"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
        <ru.igaleksus.Game2048.CellView
                android:id="@+id/cell15"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text=""/>
    </TableRow>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/score_text_size_for_large_screen"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:text="Score: 0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/startAgain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
                android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
                android:text="@string/play_again_button"
                android:background="@color/button_color"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>



</ru.igaleksus.Game2048.FieldView>
```

CellView and FieldView is my custom Views. First one - extending TextView, and its peculiarity is that it's redraw itself with new color, every time it's get the new label. Second one - extending TableLayout and almost indistinguishable from it. The problem is that I'm trying to create an animation for the movement of cells from one position to another. For this, I calculate the position of each cell by the method getLocationInWindow:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) startNewGame();
        else {
            gameStateKeeper = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(CURRENT_GAME_STATE_KEY_FOR_SAVING_STATE);
            scoreTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(CURRENT_SCORE_STATE_KEY_FOR_SAVING_STATE));
            scoreTextView.invalidate();
            restorePreviousGame();
            myField.invalidate();
            }

        myField.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    myField.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    myField.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

               for (int i = 0; i < myCells.length; i++){
                   myCells[i].positionOnScreen = new int[2];
                   myCells[i].getLocationInWindow(myCells[i].positionOnScreen);

               }
               animate(myCells[4], myCells[0], OFFSET_DIRECTION_VERTICAL_UP);


            }
        });


}
```

and then, in a method of creating animation retrieves the results for each cell. Then I use these coordinates as parameters in the constructor TranslateAnimation.

```
        protected void animate(CellView from, CellView to, int direction){

        CellView tempCellForAnimation = new CellView(myField.getContext());
        tempCellForAnimation.setText(from.getText());
        to.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        from.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        float animXStartPoint = 0;
        float animXEndPoint = 0;
        float animYStartPoint = 0;
        float animYEndPoint = 0;


        switch (direction){
            case OFFSET_DIRECTION_VERTICAL_UP:
                Log.d("MYSUPERTAG2", Integer.toString(from.getPositionOnScreen()[1]));
                animYEndPoint = to.getPositionOnScreen()[1];
                animYStartPoint = from.getPositionOnScreen()[1];

                break;
            case OFFSET_DIRECTION_VERTICAL_DOWN:
                break;
            case OFFSET_DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL_LEFT:
                break;
            case OFFSET_DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL_RIGHT:
                break;
        }

        TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, -10,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, -10,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, animYStartPoint,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, animYEndPoint);

        ta.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        ta.setDuration(1000);
        myField.addView(tempCellForAnimation);
  tempCellForAnimation.startAnimation(ta);
    }
```

And the result is not quite the way I expected. The cell does not move between the coordinates obtained in getLocationInWindow. They moving, but not between real positions of this two cells, that I delegate to this method in parameters. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I would like to know, maybe there is some way to add a visible object in Activiti, but not add it to the root element of the Layout, and just get it to perform a specific animation and then disappear? Or, it may be better to use at all some other method of animation. Thanks.